# preg_match url reconise for ifstatement

Tags: php, regex

We are bizzy writing a script that can see if the get variable is nl (dutch):
As far I can see he only gets the 'nl', but we want the script to see if there are slashes: /nl/ . What is the best way to do this :) ?

```
<? if(preg_match( '/^nl.*/', $_GET['bigtree_htaccess_url'])){
}?>
```

Comment: Need to give some examples of `$_GET['bigtree_htaccess_url']` and what should match.

Comment: Don't use `/` as the delimiter... although the pattern you are showing here doesn't have a `/` in it so that shouldn't be your current issue.

Comment: `strpos($_GET['bigtree_htaccess_url'], '/nl/') !== false`